# OutputTooSmallUTxO even with 2 ADA

Tags: output, mint, transaction

I get OutputTooSmallUTxO even with 2 ADA, is there any formula to predict the min output?

```
Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraMary (ApplyTxError [LedgerFailure (UtxowFailure (UtxoFailure (OutputTooSmallUTxO [(Addr Testnet (KeyHashObj (KeyHash "fd39564503fb2202a2fcbe55dd3bb54cc4121c9a5d729a384e432d49")) (StakeRefBase (KeyHashObj (KeyHash "b4f1c2fbf4268fb784ff29631c4bb96e9d6cb3c6764f9c0718ab641b"))),Value 2000000 (fromList [(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "c3a79051ed13af016c01b2d639518620939328b4850c573169c35a65"},fromList [("43dff6dc96b32060",1),("ALIENS1",1),("SpaceBeep",1),("ack2",1),("electri2c",1),("electric",1),("shock2a",1),("spacesound",1)])]))])))])
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was easily researchable (answer found in ~15 min) and is not up to the standards of comprehensive, unique questions that is usually expected of Stack Exchange answers.

Comment: Didn't see this before, but also look at @NikeDattani 's comment below under the answer for more feedback.

Comment: wutzeber: I was not one of the 2 users that downvoted, nor was I the one that initiated the close voting. But [ignoring this advice here](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/64/outputtoosmallutxo-even-with-2-ada#comment48_66) has started to cost you, and it will probably get worse over time if you continue to (appear to) take no notice.

Answer (score 2):

It seems we have an answer in the Cardano documentation library [Native tokens - Minimum Ada value requirement](https://docs.cardano.org/native-tokens/minimum-ada-value-requirement):

For a UTxO containing a token bundle B the min-ada-value calculation is as follows :

```
Case 1 : Token bundle B in the UTxO u contains only ada (no other tokens) minAda (u) = minUTxOValue

Case 2 : Token bundle B in the UTxO u contains ada as well as other tokens minAda (u) = max (minUTxOValue, (quot (minUTxOValue, adaOnlyUTxOSize)) * (utxoEntrySizeWithoutVal + (size B)))
```

it is too much information to fully paste it here

Comment: Users throughout the SE network are expected to "basic research" before asking a question, which is the reason why the network is respected so much for having "high-quality content'. If you were able to find the answer in 14 minutes after asking the question, perhaps you shouldn't have asked the question? I do appreciate the enthusiasm though!

Comment: @NikeDattani thank you i was looking for this information pretty long, it was a fortuity that i found the answer shortly after posting here, but maybe i just was to dumb to find the right keywords, hope others are smarter than me =)

Comment: Disagree this should have been closed. 
The docs are wordy, unclear, and talks of 'change at fork' (years ago). Plutus lib doesn't implement this fn and its "minUtxo" is hard coded. 
A lot of people hit this error. There still isn't a good answer to this Q